# jQuery events not working within iframe?

Tags: jquery, events, iframe, loading

I am having some issues with `focus(function(){})` and `blur(function(){})` within a script that is nested within a dynamically loaded iframe..

Below is the script tag WITHIN the iframe being dynamically loaded. Any event I throw into the script markup is not working, simple things like a `$('input').click(function(){alert('fired')});` will not even run. I am not sure what is going on.

Yes, jQuery is being loaded into the iframe in the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.form .field-content').find('input, select, textarea').focus(function() {
            $(this).closest('.field').addClass('focused');
        });

        $('.form .field-content').find('input, select, textarea').blur(function() {
            $(this).closest('.field').removeClass('focused');
        });

        $('.form .field-content').find('input, select').keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('.form').find('.button').first().click();
            }
        });

        $('.form .button').focus(function() {
            $(this).addClass('focused');
        });

        $('.form .button').blur(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('focused');
        });

        // focus on first field
        $('.form .field-content').find('input, select, textarea').first().focus();

    });
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Does this work when you load the iframe URL directly in your browser, rather than as an iframe?

Comment: I believe that the problem that you are facing relates to how you load the iframe . Instead of loading it dynamically using script, load the iframe statically and see if it works. Are you able to see the script elements in the injected frame source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the problem is the iframe content haven't been loaded, try

```
$("#Your-Iframe-Id").load(function (){
    // write your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for content that is dynamicaly loaded you should take a look at jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function

Comment: Using the live function in this scenario instead of bind is making no difference.

Comment: can you please paste here some more code? html and iframe where you jQuery doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Is the iframe loading a URL that is a different domain than the parent container?  If so, you won't be able to use javascript to manipulate its contents.

Comment: I don't think it matters in this case, the javascript doing the manipulation is within the html file loaded into the iframe. I am not manipulating the frame from the topmost window.

Answer (score 0):

I think :

```
$('.form .field-content').find('input, select, textarea').focus(function() {
        $(this).closest('.field').addClass('focused');
    });
```

should be:

```
$('.form .field-content').find('input, select, textarea').each(function(index) {
        $(this).focus(function(){
           alert('element ' + index + ' focused');
         });
         alert('bind focus event in element ' + index);
    });
```

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with security in your browser.  Fiddle with some of the settings for the zone and see if that helps.

What browser are you using?